# Need to monitor CPU/memory for a specific process using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a process running on windows machine and i need to monitor the CPU/memory consumption using nodejs.

As i am new to nodejs and checked few of the modules available but they are for linux based system not for windows.

Comment: You should include the list of modules you checked out. Perhaps one has a windows mode and somebody can point that out.